# service nginx stop fails without any feedback

Tags: 16.04, nginx

When I run `sudo service nginx stop`, nginx is not stopped and there are no message printed on the screen, and the prompt is back immediately:

```
user:/etc/nginx$ sudo service nginx stop
user:/etc/nginx$
```

I think there is usually a message, but it is not there.

Here are my ps results:

```
root     28527  0.0  0.2 130368  1484 ?        Ss   02:46   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 28528  0.0  0.7 131368  3776 ?        S    02:46   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Here are nginx status

```
sudo service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-23 03:06:51 UTC; 55min ago
  Process: 28519 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28633 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28629 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 19943 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

My nginx files are valid when I checked with -t

Comment: There has not been a 'stop' status/progress message since 14.04, since the main processes no longer spit data out to `stdout` and are instead intercepted by `systemd`.  This is an annoyance, but ultimately there's nothing we can do about *that* part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue where *sometimes* the `nginx` process can't be stopped with `service nginx stop` or `systemctl stop nginx`.

In those rare cases (it comes up occasionally, but is *not* easy to reproduce the case to fix the problem), you'll have to do this the 'old-fashioned' way.

First, you have to kill existing `nginx` processes.

```
sudo kill $(pidof nginx)
```

This will kill off the existing NGINX processes so that you don't have any running.

From there, you can then start processes anew with `sudo service nginx start` or similar.  You should also be able to stop nginx processes after you start them up again, now, as well, using `sudo service nginx stop` as you normally would.

(I've been looking into this issue for well over two years now and can never reproduce these cases, the only times I've ever encountered this issue *myself* was when I upgraded from 1.10.x to 1.12.x, and only ever ran into it *once*, so it's an impossible-to-reproduce issue, therefore it's nigh impossible to actually find out how to prevent this issue happening in the future)

Comment: Thanks! I also found out the cause of my issue was certbot: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/5486